# How to edit the format of citations? E.g. author et al, where "et al" must be italic?

Tags: citing, natbib

```
\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{lineno,hyperref}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[singlelinecheck=off]{caption}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{natbib}
%Import the natbib package and sets a bibliography  and citation styles
\bibliographystyle{agsm}
\setcitestyle{authoryear,open={(},close={)}} 
\begin{document}
provide safe and hygienic environment to worker
\citep{davim2007turning},
\section*{References}
\bibliography{file}
\bibliographystyle{sample}
\end{document}
```

[image: The reference is given in the image, where there is normal formatted "et al.", i need it in italic form. Kindly help in this matter.]

The reference is given in the image, where there is normal formatted "et al.", I need it in italic form.

Comment: Welcome, you have two `bibliographystyle` statements in your example. Does that work?

Comment: The formatting of the string "et al." is determined by the bibliography style that's in use.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you're using the `agsm` bibliography style. (Do delete the instruction `\bibliographystyle{sample}`.) If that's the case, you could proceed as follows:

- Find the file `agsm.bst` in your TeX distribution. Make a copy of this file and call the copy, say, `agsmetal.bst`. (Do not edit an original file of the TeX distribution directly.)
- Open the file `agsmetal.bst` in a text editor; the program you use to edit your tex files will do fine.
- In this file, globally replace all five instances of `et~al.` with `\textit{et~al.}`.
- Save the file `agsmetal.bst`, either in the directory where your main tex files are located or in a directory that's searched by your TeX distribution. If you choose the latter method, be sure to also update the filename database of your TeX distribution.
- In your main tex file, change the instruction `\bibliographystyle{agsm}` to `\bibliographystyle{agsmetal}` and perform a full recompile cycle: LaTeX - BibTeX - LaTeX - LaTeX.

Happy BibTeXing!